# two labels horizontally in tableview?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uilabel, interface-builder

[image]

I would like to have two labels in my tableview. 
but the label resize option is disabled.
How to have the two labels horizontally?

Comment: If you need two labels in each cell, you could put them both in a horizontal stack view, then use auto layout constraints to place the stackview within the cell.

Comment: Looks like you are using a standard "Basic" cell. Use a Custom cell, and add the labels yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag a horizontal UIStackView from object library and set it's constraints like this inside the cell

[image]

//

drag 2 labels inside it and make the distribution .FillEqually

//
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may need AutoLayout and Custom Tableview Call. Use two different labels, e.g. one for username (left aligned text) and another for garbage text (right aligned text).

Now, set **Content Compression Resistance Priority** for one of both label, according to your requirement for data visibility when there is long texts in user name.

Look at these snapshots:

Labels with default `content compression resistance priority`

[image]

I changed `content compression resistance priority` for label `blablabla blablabla`, from `750` to `749`.

Result is:

[image]

For more details see Apple document: [Setting Content-Hugging and Compression-Resistance Priorities](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH10-SW1)

Answer (score 1):

Select UIlabel instead of the cell and then you can set Auto resize like follow.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you want a easy and quick fix for it, implement a stack view inside the tableview cell. You can change the stackview as you want and also you dont have to worry about applying constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have selected Label?

If you know about Layout constraints, it will be easier than this auto resizer.

Label 1==> Set Leading, Top & Bottom constraints to SuperView. Set Trailing constraint to Label2.

Label2==> Set Trailing, Top & Bottom constraints to SuperView. Set Trailing constraint to Label2.

Now, after this, it will show Red error arrow. Now, you have to decide which Lable width is a priority. After deciding, select that Lable and set Horizontal Content Hugging to 251(High) and Comprehensive to 751(High). Also, change lower priority label Content Hugging and Comprehensive to 249 and 749 respectively. Now, Red error arrow will not be shown and in the cell it will show all text in both labels without and cut.